# Correct way to access data in ASP.NET web pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf-data-services, data-access-layer

I have a WCF Data Service that exposes my data model. Data security/filtering and business rules are enforced using query intercepters and service operations based on current user in the Forms Authentication cookie.

The data service is used to feed AJAX controls on some pages and may also be used by a mobile application at some point.

I also have several non-AJAX MVC views that need to display and edit the same data. If I were to use Entity Framework directly in the controllers I would need to reimplement any relevant data filtering for the logged in user. Is the correct approach is query the same data service locally within the same application?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to refactor your DataFiltering layer such that it can be used in both cases (i.e. your existing WCFDS and directly to EF), by pulling it out into its own separate module with a wrapper to abstract away the details of which authentication method is being used (FormsAuthentication or the LoggedIn user). This has a bit more upfront cost in implementation, but its definitely much more efficient than re-querying the same application (and will save you some cost later on if you have to implement another module in the future).

Comment: If I do that, won't I lose the ability to perform advanced LINQ operations on the objects returned? I can currently use LINQ or ODATA to perform any kind of operation on the WCFDS. What about updates? Will I have to write separate functions for every possible update/insert operation I might perform?

I'm currently using EF in database-first mode. If I switch to code first mode will I be able to perform filtering in the entity classes? If so then it would retain the full LINQ feature set and insert/update ability.

Comment: I was thinking of something more fine grained, where you would continue to use the same query interceptors and service operations on your existing WCFDS, change their implementations to call a separate module that can be used by your MVC views as well. I would definitely recommend a code first model as you suggest in this case, it gives you the level of control you need to make that factoring easier.

Comment: That would result in people working on different parts of the site forgetting to filter data or rolling their own filtering instead of calling the common filtering functions. I want any means of data access to be already filtered (i.e. the DbContext or WCFDS if requerying)